# Hybris - integration test - how to use @NeedsEmbeddedServer annotation

Tags: localhost, integration-testing, sap-commerce-cloud

I am having a web extension with several endpoints implemented in the controller.
Now I want to test those endpoints with e. g. GET OR POST request like https://localhost:9002/myExtension/myEndpoint

I thought I could achieve that via integration test and annotate the class with @NeedsEmbeddedServer(webextension="myExtension")

My implementation looks similar like that

```
@NeedsEmbeddedServer(webextension="myextension)
@IntegrationTest
public class myClass implements ServiceLayerTransactionalTest {

@Test
public void myTest {
doSomeRequestHere();
}
```

When I run my test (which I do via ANT) the server starts up but I am not able to do the request. I also placed a timer in my test to check if localhost is running on several ports but I couldnt reach it.

In general what is the purpose of @NeedsEmbeddedServer annotation and can I achieve my goal like that?

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860746/how-to-write-unit-test-for-hybris-occ-controllers

Comment: Thanks - I checked that already but doesn't answer my question